# android.os.FileUriExposedException: at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I'm following [this tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) for using FileProvider instead of `Uri.FromFile()` But I'm not sure how to use FileProvider in my service.

`FileProvider.getUriForFile()` expects a context for the first argument but because  I'm using this in my service, I don't have an activity context.

What am I supposed to do?

I need to change this:

```
Uri swatchImageUri = Uri.fromFile(favoritesImageFile);
```

To what they suggestion above.

Here's the current exception I've been getting without using FileProvider:

```
2019-07-23 23:04:42.748 11034-11034/com.company.projname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.projname, PID: 11034
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.projname/cache/colors.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1978)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2371)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:963)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10216)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10222)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10201)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1667)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
```

Code snippet:

```
public void shareColorSwatch(SwatchViewModel model){

        try {
            String swatchName = model.First.get().Name.get().replaceAll("\\s","").replaceAll("'", "") + "_" +
                    model.Second.get().Name.get().replaceAll("\\s","").replaceAll("'", "") + "_" +
                    model.Third.get().Name.get().replaceAll("\\s","").replaceAll("'", "");


            Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            int screenWidth =  display.getWidth();
            int screenHeight = display.getHeight();

            Bitmap swatchBitmap = createColorSwatchBitmap(model, screenWidth, screenHeight);

            String fileName = String.format("swatch_%s.png", swatchName);
            File swatchImageFile = getImageFile(activity,fileName, swatchBitmap, true);
            Uri swatchImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(//,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    swatchImageFile);
            //Uri swatchImageUri = Uri.fromFile(swatchImageFile);
            shareImage(activity,swatchName,swatchImageUri);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of your service where you are calling the method?

Comment: @JuanDanielOrnella posted. Oh I was just thinking it should just be activity above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Int the line:

```
 Uri swatchImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(//,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    swatchImageFile);
```

Pass activity as first argument:

```
 Uri swatchImageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                swatchImageFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What am I supposed to do?

`Service` is a `Context`. So, if you are calling `getUriForFile()` directly in a `Service`, use `this` for the `Context`.

Comment: I tried to do that but it won't let me use this: Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.company.projname.service.ShareService', required: 'android.content.Context'

Comment: @Euridice01: Then `ShareService` does not extend from `Service`.

Comment: no it doesn't you're right. It's just a service class but it doesn't extend from Service. What can I do now?

Comment: @Euridice01: You seem to be using `startActivityForResult()` with this `Intent` that you are creating, so you must have an `Activity` or `Fragment` that is making that call. So, get your `Context` from there.